# Sudo and file permissions

Tags: linux, sudo

I am configuring sudo on a server and have the following question. I only want a user group to run the `/sbin/ifconfig`. I have configured sudo:

```
User_Alias ​​NETWORK = user1 
Cmnd_Alias ​​NETWORKING = /sbin/ifconfig 
Host_Alias ​​MYHOSTS = localhost
```

rule:

```
NETWORK MYHOSTS = (root) NETWORKING
```

It works well for user *user1*: `sudo ifconfig` asks the password. But, I see that any computer user can run ifconfig also because the permissions on this file in `/sbin` are 755. Is it right? Should I also change the file permissions?

Comment: Usually every user can run `ifconfig`, but cannot make modifications like `ifconfig eth0 down` which requires root/sudo.

Comment: Then sudo command not completely blocked, but only certain actions. Although this is not a user in the sudo file permissions will continue having regular file, is that correct?

Comment: Correct, if I understand you right. In my own words: sudo only checks permissions if a command is executed via `sudo command`. Otherwise only the file system permissions (or other security mechanisms) are obeyed.

Comment: @aelbaz: What do you mean by 'permissions will continue having regular file'?  The effect of `sudo /sbin/ifconfig (...)` is to run the `/sbin/ifconfig` command as user `root`, who can do more with that command than a regular user can, not because of the permissions set on `/sbin/ifconfig` or because of the lines in the `sudo` configuration, but because of permissions set on other files that are used by `/sbin/ifconfig`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the sudo manpage:

> sudo allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user, as specified by the security policy.

That does not affect the regular (file system) permissions. So, if an executable has permissions 755 (`-rwxr-xr-x`) *every* user on the system can execute it. But -- depending on the executable -- for some operations you get a permission denied error:

```
$ ls -l /sbin/ifconfig
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 67912 May 11  2013 /sbin/ifconfig
$ whoami
user
$ /sbin/ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:29886 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:17383 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3706932 (3.5 MiB)  TX bytes:34965406 (33.3 MiB)
$ /sbin/ifconfig eth0 down
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
$ sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth0 down
[sudo] password for user:
 - no error -
$
```

Please note that changing the permissions of `/sbin/ifconfig` to 700 (`-rwx-----`) will prevent normal users to execute it, but there might be others means to gain the information. E. g. the IP address via `ip address` or the `/proc` file system.